# Nextjs fatal production only error after adding new package

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, modulenotfounderror

We have a NextJs app that is running for couple of years in production.

Recently I added `storybook-addon-pseudo-states` addon ran the code locally and tested and pushed to production. The app was running perfectly locally. believe it or not after pushing to production, production entirely went down with this weird error.

```
{"statusCode":500,"code":"MODULE_NOT_FOUND","error":"Internal Server Error","message":"Cannot find module 'react-is'\nRequire stack:\n- /opt/webapp/node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.cjs.js\n- /opt/webapp/.next/server/pages/_document.js\n- /opt/webapp/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/require.js\n- /opt/webapp/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/load-components.js\n- /opt/webapp/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/api-utils.js\n- /opt/webapp/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js\n- /opt/webapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js\n- /opt/webapp/server.js"}
```

This is our package.json.

```
{
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development yarn server-remove-types && yarn server-watch",
    "build": "yarn server-remove-types && yarn server-compile && yarn server-copy && next build",
    "server-remove-types": "flow-remove-types --all --pretty src/server --out-dir .untyped/server",
    "server-compile": "ncc build .untyped/server/index.js --out .dist --minify --external next --external grpc",
    "server-copy": "node ./util/copy.js --from .dist/index.js --to server.js",
    "server-watch": "yarn server-watch-remove-types & yarn server-watch-compile & yarn server-watch-nodemon",
    "server-watch-nodemon": "node .dist/index.js",
    "server-watch-remove-types": "node util/watch-flow-remove-types.js --from src/server --to .untyped/server",
    "server-watch-compile": "yarn server-compile --watch",
    "lint-javascript": "eslint src",
    "format": "eslint src --fix",
    "type-install": "flow-typed install",
    "type-upgrade": "flow-typed update",
    "type-check": "flow check --color=always --show-all-errors",
    "test-unit": "NODE_ENV=test jest --config ./config/jest.unit.config.js --colors",
    "test-unit-watch": "yarn test-unit --watchAll --coverage false",
    "test-unit-update-snapshots": "yarn test-unit --updateSnapshot",
    "test-endpoints": "NODE_ENV=test jest --config ./config/jest.endpoints.config.js src/test/endpoints.spec.js",
    "test-bdd": "echo 'Not implemented.'",
    "test-contract": "echo 'Not implemented.'",
    "test-e2e": "echo 'Not implemented.'",
    "test-e2e-debug": "echo 'Not implemented.'",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 3001",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -o ./src/stories/storybook"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=12"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "extends @dpgr/browserslist-config"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@dpgr/browserslist-config": "^1.1.0",
    "@dpgr/react-components": "^3.7.0",
    "@sentry/browser": "6.10.0",
    "@sentry/node": "6.10.0",
    "@sentry/tracing": "6.10.0",
    "@tippy.js/react": "^2.2.3",
    "@vercel/ncc": "^0.31",
    "axios": "0.18.1",
    "babel-plugin-superjson-next": "^0.3.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "chokidar": "^3.3.1",
    "color": "^3.1.0",
    "convert-array-to-csv": "^1.0.9",
    "cookie": "^0.4.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.4.1",
    "dompurify": "^2.0.2",
    "draft-js": "^0.11.0",
    "draft-js-export-html": "^1.3.3",
    "draft-js-import-html": "^1.3.3",
    "fastify": "^2.0.0",
    "fastify-cookie": "^3.0.2",
    "flow-remove-types": "^2.115.0",
    "focus-visible": "^5.0.0",
    "formik": "^1.3.2",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "google-protobuf": "^3.14.0",
    "grpc": "^1.24.4",
    "grpc-web": "^1.2.1",
    "http-status-codes": "^1.3.0",
    "iban": "^0.0.14",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "minimist": "^1.2.0",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "next": "^10.0.0",
    "next-cookies": "^2.0.3",
    "next-redux-wrapper": "^7.0.0",
    "node-xlsx": "^0.15.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "openid-client": "^3.13.0",
    "p-queue": "^6.2.1",
    "path-to-regexp": "^6.2.0",
    "re-reselect": "^3.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-aria-modal": "^4.0.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.11.1",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.1",
    "react-datepicker": "^3.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-paginate": "^6.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-select": "^3.0.8",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.1",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.3",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.0.0",
    "styled-reboot": "^4.0.1",
    "superjson": "^1.7.5",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.1",
    "yup": "^0.28.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.15",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.13.14",
    "@babel/helper-builder-react-jsx": "^7.15.4",
    "@babel/helper-builder-react-jsx-experimental": "^7.12.11",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types": "^7.4.4",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "6.3.12",
    "@storybook/addon-controls": "^6.3.12",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "6.3.12",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "6.3.12",
    "@storybook/react": "6.3.12",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "12.0.0",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "7.0.1",
    "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "^0.4.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-inline-react-svg": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.0",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.0",
    "css-loader": "6.4.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.6.1",
    "eslint": "^7.24.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.0.1",
    "eslint-import-resolver-babel-module": "^5.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^23.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2",
    "fastify-http-proxy": "^2.1.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.110.0",
    "flow-typed": "^2.4.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-styled-components": "^7.0.5",
    "mockdate": "^2.0.5",
    "pretty": "^2.0.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3",
    "redux-saga-test-plan": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-testkit": "^1.0.6",
    "storybook-addon-designs": "6.2.0",
    "storybook-addon-next-router": "3.0.8",
    "style-loader": "3.3.0",
    "supertest": "^6.1.6"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {}
}
```

These are the only changes made to package.json, plus few small changes in storybook stories.

[Changes to package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTsZu.png)

Any idea what is the root cause for this fatal production only error?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue when running `next build && next start` locally (or whatever equivalent you have for running the production app)?

Answer (score 0):

The error says you're missing the library `react-is` and based on your `package.json` it doesn't appear to be installed.

The two scenarios that come to mind to explain erroring after package install / only in production.

##### Scenario 1

Someone could have manually deleted `react-is` from the `package.json` at some point in time after the last package manager sync and prior to your screenshot.

Package managers sync the changes in `package.json` when performing installs, updates, and uninstalls.  Meaning, when you added the storybook plugin it removed the `react-is` package because it was no longer listed in the `package.json` file.

##### Scenario 2

Since it's only happening in production the app might not be using `react-is` but it is still included in a file.

```
import ReactIs from 'react-is'
```

Search your app for `react-is` - if it's not used, remove the unused statements - if it's used you need to install the package.

Comment: react-is is not directly used or imported anywhere in code. It is dependency of dependency. I see it exists in yarn.lock file before and after the commit. 
since its a dependency of dependency I see a "require('react-is)" in bundled _document.js file. which didn't resolve and throw the error. but since 'react-is' is in yarn.lock before and after commit, I don't know why it couldn't resolve it.

Comment: Try to delete your yarn.lock and tell yarn to rebuild file with a command like yarn upgrade